# A problem with recalling from 2 table, by id, how much customer deposited, in table

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a crm, for my own learning.

And I have a problem because I have 1 table "client" and in the other table I store the deposit of this client, I need on the page in the table to show the clients deposit, with the filter "Status=4", I tried to do it as annoate but then I can not bring up the corresponding id.

Models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.lastname

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Client'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Client'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, null=True)
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='salesman')
    retention = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='retention')
    reg_time = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Operation(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.name + ' ' + self.client.lastname + '  Cash: ' + str(self.cash)

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client')
    cash = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bank')
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stat')
    who = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ftd_employees')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Operations'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Operations'
```

client_list.html

```
<tbody>
                            {%  for c in clients_list %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ c.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.name }} {{ c.lastname }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.phone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.salesman.name }} {{ c.salesman.lastname }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.retention.name }} {{ c.retention.lastname }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.phone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.reg_time }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.depo }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
```

views.py

```
@property
def client_ftd(self):
    depo = Client.objects.annotate(Operation=Count("kto__id")).annotate(totals=Sum("kto__cash")).filter(kto__status=4)

    return depo


def client_list(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.all()
    clients_list = Client.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'client_list.html', {'clients_list': clients_list,
                                                'employee': employee, 'client_ftd': client_ftd})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `clients_list = Client.objects.all()`.

For the solution you need to replace `.all` with `.annotate`. Subsequently you have to open a parenthesis with your depo, so `(depo=Sum('operation__cash', filter=Q(operation__status=4)))`. As you can see, the `"Status = 4"` filter is used.

This way you will call back from 2 table, by id, how much customer deposited, in table :)

```
@property
def client_ftd(self):
    depo = Client.objects.annotate(Operation=Count("kto__id")).annotate(totals=Sum("kto__cash")).filter(kto__status=4)
    return depo

def client_list(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.all()

    clients_list = Client.objects.annotate(depo=Sum('operation__cash', filter=Q(operation__status=4))) #update 

    return render(request, 'client_list.html', {'clients_list': clients_list,
                                                'employee': employee, 'client_ftd': client_ftd})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for this simple query:

```
clients_list = Client.objects.annotate(depo=Sum('operation__cash', filter=Q(operation__status=4)))
```

Looking at your code I think you really have to learn some more about:

- properties (@property decorator is intended to be used inside a class on a method; why did you put it in the views ??),
- aggregate queries (what's "kto", what's the point of annotate(Operation=Count("kto__id")) ??) ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can optimize your database query using this query in `view.py`:

```
Operation.objects.filter(status__id = 4).annotate(depo = Sum('cash')).values(
    'client__id',
    'client__name',
    'client__email',
    'client__phone',
    'client__salesman__name',
    'client__salesman_lastname',
    'client__relation__name',
    'client__relation.lastname',
    'client__reg_time',
)
```

Check if it works. It should only return the fields you need and work more efficiently.
Avoid using loops in Python. The database is much more efficient.